# Явный возврат объекта

Tags: javascript

помогите, пожалуйста расшифровать этот код и подскажите как перевести его в явный возврат объекта?

```
    'use strict'
const newPost = (post, addedAt = Date()) => ({
    ...post,
    addedAt,
})
const firstPost = {
    author: 'Vlad',
    id: 1,
}
newPost(firstPost)
console.table(newPost(firstPost))
```

Comment: Что такое «явный возврат объекта»? Вы хотите `=> { return {...post, addedAt}; }` или о чём речь?

Comment: @Grundy, можешь пожалуйста закрыть как дубликат к этому: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1404652/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%85-js/1404673#1404673